# Undefined Symbols even with explicit links

Tags: linux, linker, g++, shared-libraries, undefined-symbol

Been dealing in linker hell for the past day and figured I'd throw this out there and see if anyone could help me out.

I have two shared libraries that I'm building: one called "libhttp" that has some helper functions for the http protocol which seems to be building for better or worse OK.  The second is called "libvpcutil" which is causing the issues.  It depends on symbols that are in libhttp so I link it against libhttp.  Here's the compilation directive (exploded from the make file) with minor things like my personal path to openssl generified:

```
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libvpcutil.so.1 -o libvpcutil.so.1.0  vpcreg/registry.o \
vpcreg/vpcreg2.o  dbase/dbase.o dbase/sqlutils.o  diaglog/diaglog.o  errmsg/errmsg.o  \
faillib/faillib.o  failover/failover.o  initerr/init_err.o  kmq/kmq.o kmq/publish.o  \
kthread/kcom.o kthread/kthread.o  libobdi/odi_serv.o  mutex/mutex.o  netserv/netserv.o  \
newmem/newmem.o  rmtstore/avlmem.o rmtstore/rmtstore.o rmtstore/shm_aloc.o  \
servhand/servhand.o  timers/timers.o  vpcstamp/vpcstamp.o  websql/websql.o  types/blob.o \
types/hitime.o types/ticks.o types/timestamp.o  odasm/odasm.o  webvibapi/webvibapi.o  \
vibusfeed/vibusfeed.o  propstore/propstore2.o  cardlib/cardlib.o cardlib/sortlist.o  \
gapi/genapi.o -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lm -lrt -lxml2 -lodbc -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -\
lcurl -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro \
-L/pathtoopenssl/openssl -lssl -lcrypto  -lxml2   -lreadline -\
lcurses -Wl,-rpath=.:/pathtobin/bin http/libhttp.so.1.0 ../ddldata/ddldata.o 
../cardddl/cardddl.o ../gendata/generic.o
```

The compilation and linking completes successfully.  Hopefully you noted the link step to http/libhttp.so.1.0.

Now, if I do a nm on libhttp.so.1.0, I get the following output (amongst others):

```
00015d5a T _ZN12http_cookiesC1Ev
00015d5a T _ZN12http_cookiesC2Ev
00015d7e T _ZN12http_cookiesD1Ev
00015d7e T _ZN12http_cookiesD2Ev
00011574 T _ZN12http_headers11url_expressERSo
00011466 T _ZN12http_headers12http_expressERSo
```

But when I do a nm on libvpcutil.so.1.0 I get essentially:

```
     U _ZN12http_cookiesC1Ev
     U _ZN12http_cookiesD1Ev
     U _ZN12http_headers11url_expressERSo
     U _ZN12http_headers3setEPKcRKSs
     U _ZN12http_headers3setEPKcS1_
     U _ZN12http_headersC1Ev
     U _ZN12http_headersD1Ev
```

I'm obviously snipping here, but where I'm stuck here is the symbols are clearly defined in libhttp, I link against it for libvpcutil, but then the symbols are undefined in libvpcutil.  This creates runtime errors.

Anyone see the issue?

Comment: It usually means that the signatures don't match. Check the source code (and put it here, if you want any help) where the functions are declared, implemented and called.

Comment: @littleadv, if the signatures didn't match the errors would happen before runtime, and you can _see_ they match just by looking at the `nm` output.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I'm sure we're looking at different things. In the question, you have two `nm` outputs, which list a bunch of functions with overloaded parameters, and only one is paired to the other.

Comment: @littleadv, I wasn't clear, I meant the OP can see if they match, and says _"I'm obviously snipping here, but where I'm stuck here is the symbols are clearly defined in libhttp"_ so I assumed they do match, checking the code isn't needed, checking the `nm` output is sufficient. The real point is that the symbols are _supposed_ to be undefined in `libvpcutil`, dynamic linking doesn't work the way the OP expects.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the expected behaviour.

Linking to a shared library is not like linking to a static library, the required symbols do not get copied into the output file, you just get a reference to the symbol which must still be resolved at run-time. So it's normal that the symbols are shown as `U` by `nm`.

What are the run-time errors?  It probably means the `libhttp.so.1.0` library isn't found at run-time.  You should be able to run `ldd` on `libvpcutil.so` and on the executable to see if they depend on `libhttp.so.1.0` and if they're finding the right one.

Does `libhttp.so.1.0` have a soname set?  If it's not the same as the filename, do you have a symlink with the same name as the soname? (e.g. if the soname is `libhttp.so.1` you'll need a symlink `libhttp.so.1 -> libhttp.so.1.0`).  I also see your `libhttp.so.1.0` is in a directory called `http` but that's not in your RPATH, so won't be found at runtime.